# Passing both List and Array as argument of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, generics, resharper, ienumerable

I want to make a method that can accept both `List<byte>` and array of bytes as argument (as Resharper suggested):

```
public static UInt16 GetSourceAddress(IEnumerable<byte> packet)
{
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(new[] {packet[4], packet[5]}, 0);
}
```

Bute I get the follwing compilation error:

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>'
```

I know I can just go ahead with two overloads with List and byte[], but what does this problem indicates? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want random access, use `IList<T>` instead:

```
public static UInt16 GetSourceAddress(IList<byte> packet)
```

Both `List<byte>` and `byte[]` implement `IList<byte>`, and it has an indexer.

Comment: Thanks Jon, partly works but I get this on another method: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<byte>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>`

Comment: @Saeid87: No, you wouldn't be able to - but there's nothing in the code you've shown which *needs* a `List<byte>`. It's hard to advise you without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, had to change other methods signature to IList<> too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static UInt16 GetSourceAddress(IEnumerable<byte> packet){  

 return BitConverter.ToUInt16(new[] {packet.ElementAt(4), packet.ElementAt(5)}, 0);
}
```